# Read JSON data from AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, function, jsonp

Consider:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/myurl",
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        contentType: "application/json",
        complete: function (data) {
                var results = data["responseText"];
                alert(results)
        },
        error: function () {
              alert("Error")
        }
 });
```

The JSON returned:

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": null, "result": "{\"ids\": [{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"Messi\"}, {\"id\": 2, \"name\": \"Ronaldo\"}]}"}
```

How can I append the data in div like the following?

```
1 Messi

2 Ronaldo
```

Comment: Loop over the array? FYI: synchronous requests are a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Pick the `ids` property from your Ajax response, loop through it and prepare your required HTML structure using that info. In the end, insert this HTML string in your HTML page.

```js
/*
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/myurl",
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        contentType: "application/json",
        complete: function (data) {
                      var response = data["responseText"];
                      var insertDatas = JSON.parse(response.result);
                      var htmlString = "";
                      insertDatas.ids.forEach(function( item ){
                          htmlString += '<li>'+item.name+'</li>';
                      });//forEach()

                      $("#players-list").html( htmlString );
                  },
                  error: function () {
                      alert("Error")
                  }
    });
*/

var response = {
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": null,
  "result":
    {"ids":
      [
       {"id": 1, "name": "Messi"},
       {"id": 2, "name": "Ronaldo"}
      ]
    }
};

var htmlString = "";
response.result.ids.forEach(function(item){
    htmlString += '<li>' + item.name + '</li>';
});//forEach()

$("#players-list").html( htmlString );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="players-list"></ol>
```

Comment: Tnx for help your example work fine but how in my solution JSon result asign to response variable? I don't have var response  when try var response = data["responseText"]  not working.

Comment: in your example, `data` itself is response. Replace `response` with `data` and use this code. it should work.

Comment: My source  http://imgur.com/a/G12Mv

Comment: not working after replace response with data

Comment: In that linked image, you have highlighted that the 2nd way works for you. You can just use that and loop through `ids`

Comment: I don't understend your last comment, I need loop through ids from data, This is actually from database!

Comment: I have updated the code in my answer. Please check the commented out section of code. I have tried to put the implementation in your code. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143697/discussion-between-mohit-bhardwaj-and-anastasia).

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Any solution how fix problem?

Comment: Are you able to join the chat linked to in my last comment?

Comment: hello, can you see my example posted on chat? Any help?

Comment: @Anastasia_ Ok. just saw your message. Checking it now